# Graph API get names from interactions with FB business page posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We're interested in getting names and IDs from likes/interactions with business page posts on FB. It seems to me that we're only able to get this data for users who have already granted our app permission both through the feed and item endpoints.

Wondering if anyone can either confirm this is the case or point me in the general direction of the correct approach for this. The post I was testing was indeed public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wanders across this, it appears that my assumptions were correct from what my continued research shows.

The route we ended up taking was to hook into the marketing API and get lead data from CTA forms on ads. Not what we were hoping for.